# Помогите пожалуйста проверить код!

Tags: c++

В с++ ещё плохо разбираюсь, пытаюсь написать код по задаче.Не понимаю правильно иду или нет.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x[3], y[3];
cin >> x[1];
cin >> y[1];
cin >> x[2];
cin >> y[2];
cin >> x[0];
cin >> y[0];

    if (x[0] > x[2] && y[0] > y[2])
    {
        cout << "NE";
    }
    else if (x[0] > x[2] && y[0] < y[1])
    {
        cout << "SE";
    }
    else if (x[0] < x[1] && y[0] < y[1])
    {
        cout << "SW";
    }
    else if (x[0] < x[1] && y[0] > y[2])
    {
        cout << "NW";
    }

/*  if (y[0] > y[2])
    {
        cout << "N";
    }
    else if (y[0] < y[1])
    {
        cout << "S";
    }
    else if (x[0] < x[2])
    {
        cout << "W";
    }
    else if (x[0] > x[2]);
    {
        cout << "E";
    }*/
   }
```

Само условие:
Программа получает на вход шесть чисел в следующем порядке: x1, y1 (координаты
юго-западного угла плота), x2, y2 (координаты
северо-восточного угла плота), x, y (координаты
пловца). Все числа целые и по модулю не
превосходят 100. Гарантируется, что x1 < x2, y1 < y2,
x ≠ x1, x ≠ x2, y ≠ y1, y ≠ y2, координаты пловца
находятся вне плота.
Если пловцу следует плыть к северной
стороне плота, программа должна вывести символ
«N», к южной – символ «S», к западной – символ
«W», к восточной – символ «E». Если пловцу
следует плыть к углу плота, нужно вывести одну из
следующих строк: «NW», «NE», «SW», «SE».

Comment: Это видно, что вы не только в паскале, но и в питоне (исходник на котором, но неверно отформатированный, привели) по нулям... А потому бесплатный совет - как раз сегодня доставили новую партию ((с) Хайнлайн) - учите С++ и пишите самостоятельно, а не пытайтесь выехать на чужих исходниках!

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием, но я не успеваю, от этого кода зависит моё дальнейшее обучение. Я уже учусь програмировать на с++, вот только задача сложная.

Comment: Да, ведь так сложно ввести пару чисел и сравнить их

Comment: *"А ты меня не жалоби" (с) Жеглов.* Это - предельно простое задание. И если бы вы набросали хоть какой-то код в данном направлении на С++, показав, что вы действительно хотите и стараетесь работать - вам бы помогли. Попробуйте, начните :) От того, что вы сдадите чужую работу - ну, вы так ничему и не научитесь, кроме побираться у других "на халяву". Думаю, что потраченные на ожидание к моменту этого моего комментария полчаса (не считая времени на поиск исходника на питоне) вы могли бы потратить и более эффективно, изучая С++...

Comment: я тут пытаюсь. И думаю ещё насчёт минимума и максимума

Comment: Внесите код в вопрос (там под ним есть пункт "править") и все же сформулируйте задание - иначе непонятно, зачем вдруг искать минимум и максимум...

Comment: Всё, я исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я бы делал так.

```
int x1,y1, x2,y2, x,y;
cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;   // Координаты плота

cin >> x >> y;                 // Координаты пловца

char V =                       // Куда плыть по вертикали?
    (y > y2) ? 'N' :           // Если высоко (севернее) - точно к северной стороне
    (y < y1) ? 'S' : 0;        // Если низко (южнее) - к южной стороне
                               // Иначе - плыть по горизонтали

char H =                       // То же самое для горизонтали
    (x > x2) ? 'E' :
    (x < x1) ? 'N' : 0;

                               // Просто выводим символы, если есть
if (V) cout << V;
if (H) cout << H;
cout << endl;
```